# Has anyone successfully downgraded there moto G v2 from lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, downgrade, motorola-moto-g2

I made the mistake of upgrading OTA to Lollipop (5.0.2) since then have been considering flushing the device down the toilet:

- Unable to answer incoming calls half the time.
- Unintuitive UI update.
- Regular drop outs when using as data hotspot.

**Has anyone managed to get there phone back to KitKat** and if so how did you do it?

My phone is the Australian Dual Sim unlocked retail version.

*Apologies to anyone that thinks it is lazy for me not to wade through every generic answer and roll the dice on bricking the phone without at least asking if someone has succeeded (or failed) with identical circumstances.*

Comment: specifically asking for success cases, instead of generic advice that's may or may not brick the device

Comment: Note this is for Asia retail..download the one which is for the australian retail  and follow the steps as mentioned in [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/100-tested-downgrade-lollipop-5-0-x-to-t3004836)

Comment: @Lucky what link provides the Australian retail ROM?

Comment: [Try this](http://www.filefactory.com/file/2rksrxgwubir/RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-27_cid7_CFC_SVC.xml.zip) obtained from [xda-devleper forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/development/stock-firmware-images-4g-3g-variants-t3065433/)

Comment: Thanks, could you narrow it down some more please?RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-27_cid7_CFC_SVC.xml.zip,
RETLA_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-24_cid12_CFC_SVC.xml.zip,
RETGBALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-23_cid7_CFC.xml.zip,
RETDEALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-23_cid7_CFC.xml.zip,
NIIBR_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-24_cid12_CFC.xml.zip,
RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-23_cid7_CFC.xml.zip,
RETBR_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-24_cid12_CFC.xml.zip,

RETDEALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-14_cid7_CFC.xml.zip
RETBR_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-18_cid12_CFC.xml.zip
RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-14_cid7_CFC_SVC.xml.zip

Comment: it seems there is no specific version for australia..u can use the generic [RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-27_cid7_CFC_SVC.xml.zip](http://www.filefactory.com/file/2rksrxgwubir/RETAILDSDSALL_XT1068_4.4.4_KXB21.85-27_cid7_CFC_SVC.xml.zip) and 21.85.27 is the updated kitkat version..

Comment: What does ...DSDS... indicate?

Comment: Found out - Dual Sim - Dual Standby... Am downloading now to see if my phone survives.

Comment: norlesh, I appreciate you caution here but Stack Exchange is for specific Q&A rather than polling the experiences of others.  Your question might be more suited to XDA or another forum where you can have a back-and-forth discussion.

Answer (score -1):

You could try restoring it to the factory settings in the boot mode.Or try this link [techdroider.com  downgrade from lollipop to kitkat](http://www.techdroider.com/2014/12/how-to-downgrade-moto-g-2nd-gen-xt1068.html).

Comment: The link you metioned - One of them commented that _"As soon as press the "Download" button it states "Sorry, this file is infected with a virus. Only the owner is allowed to download infected files."_.. so It may be potentially be a virus or false positive or you may never know..its risky anyway..and more over Factory reset erases all data from the phone but it wont change/downgrade the OS..

Comment: No it actually works fine. I did the same to my pone as well

Comment: You mean factory resetting or the link that you have provided.? if its the link that you have provided you should explain the steps you have done to successfully restore to kitkat..Provding link only answer will be valid only till the link is available..So it is better to explain the steps in the answer itself..;)

Comment: I did the factory resetting thing. But i wouldn't recommend it though , you lose your data

Comment: I get the indication from the comments on that page that the ROM is for the Asian market - would this apply to an Australian phone (assuming it's not a virus)?

Comment: Yes it applies to all.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on this site since they become obsolete as soon as the link expires. Would you want your answer to be worthless in the near future? I guess no! So, please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/111402/edit) and add the relevant parts here (you may quote (with proper credit) as well).